# I have added favorite icon in angular but color is not changing and when i refresh it is not showing as favorite

Tags: angular, favicon

[image]
I have added favorite icon in angular but color is not changing and when i refresh it is not showing as favorite.

favourite.component.html

in these favourite icon i have added but color is not changing.

```
<div class="dir-alp-con-right-1">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="row span-none" *ngIf="!isSpinner">
              <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let x of RentData | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 9, currentPage: p }">
                <a (click)="sendRentdetails(x)">
                  <!-- <a [routerLink]="['/saleconcreteplantdetails']" >   -->
                  <div class="list-mig-like-com com-mar-bot-30">
                    <div class="list-mig-lc-img"> <img src="{{x.image1}}" alt="Image"> </div>
                  </div>
                </a>
                    <div class="list-mig-lc-con">
                        <div class="primeimage">
                            <button class="btn btn-success">Rs. {{x.price}}</button>
                            <button class="favouri" (click)="isFavoritee(x.ad_Id)"><i class="fa"
                              [ngClass]="{'fa-heart' : isFavorite , 'fa-heart-o' : !isFavorite }"></i></button>
                        </div>
                      <div class="list-rat-ch list-room-rati">
                        <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{x.location}} </div>
                      <h5>{{x.name}}</h5>
                      <h6>Other Machines > For Rent Other Machines</h6>
                    </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: favourite.component.ts

Comment: isFavoritee(elem: any) {
    this.toggle = !this.toggle;
    this.favouritedata = [];
    const favo = {
      'login_Id': this.localservice.getLoginId() ? this.localservice.getLoginId() : '',
      'ad_id' : elem ? elem : '',
      'category_Id' : 27,
      'mode': 'INSERT'
    };
    this.authservice.post('/api/Favourite/insert', favo).subscribe(data1 => {
      this.favouritedata = data1;
      console.log(this.favouritedata);
    }, error => {
      alert('something went wrong');
    });
  }

Comment: color is not changing, please help reagarding these

Comment: You can check the Image for FAVOURITE.COMPONENT.TS  . In the TITLE.

Comment: Edit the additional info into your question instead of posting it as a comment

Comment: i am not able to change the code. In HTML file Favourite Button is there. For TS file you can refer the image "enter image description here". Kindly help me regarding the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When asking a question about a problem with code, people who are volunteering to help need the text of the code. Images of the code are not an acceptable substitute. [see here...](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: i have added the text format of the code. Kindly help me regarding the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
isFavoritee(elem: any) {
  this.toggle = !this.toggle;
  this.favouritedata = [];
  const favo = {
    'login_Id': this.localservice.getLoginId() ? this.localservice.getLoginId() : '',
    'ad_id' : elem ? elem : '',
    'category_Id' : 27,
    'mode': 'INSERT'
  };
  this.authservice.post('/api/Favourite/insert', favo).subscribe(data1 => {
    this.favouritedata = data1;
    console.log(this.favouritedata);
  }, error => {
      alert('something went wrong');
  });
}
```

Comment: Functionalities are working fine only problem is, when we click on the icon it is not selected and if refresh also it should be selected only. Kindly help me regarding the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My Question is when click on favorite button, color is not changing and when i refresh favorite is not selected.

```
favorite.component.html

<div class="dir-alp-con-right-1">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="row span-none" *ngIf="!isSpinner">
          <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let x of RentData | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 9, currentPage: p }">
            <a (click)="sendRentdetails(x)">
              <!-- <a [routerLink]="['/saleconcreteplantdetails']" >   -->
              <div class="list-mig-like-com com-mar-bot-30">
                <div class="list-mig-lc-img"> <img src="{{x.image1}}" alt="Image"> </div>
              </div>
            </a>
                <div class="list-mig-lc-con">
                    <div class="primeimage">
                        <button class="btn btn-success">Rs. {{x.price}}</button>
                        <button class="favouri" (click)="isFavoritee(x.ad_Id)"><i class="fa"
                          [ngClass]="{'fa-heart' : isFavorite , 'fa-heart-o' : !isFavorite }"></i></button>
                    </div>
                  <div class="list-rat-ch list-room-rati">
                    <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{x.location}} </div>
                  <h5>{{x.name}}</h5>
                  <h6>Other Machines > For Rent Other Machines</h6>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```